# How to change nodemon default start file?

Tags: nodemon

i have a web-application. I want to use nodemon with it. To start my application need to run **'node ./bin/www'**, but nodemon default run another file. And my web-applications doesn't aviable.

When i type in cmd

```
nodemon
```

i got:

```
[nodemon] 1.14.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

but i want change default start file from `node app.js` to `node ./bin/www`

How can i do this?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "loc8r",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "4.13.9",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.9",
    "readline": "1.3.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nodemon should pick up what ever file is in `"main": "file_to_be_executed.js",` so if www is your file to be executed, change: `"main": "app.js",` to: `"main": "./bin/www",`

Comment: In case if you are using Express Js as framework then even ```bin/www``` runs the ```app.js``` and its been included at the first line of www file like
```var app = require('../app');```